# Is using the polynomial kernel equivalent to adding features?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

On page 352, **"An Introduction to Statistical Learning"** by James et al. explains the effect of using the polynomial kernel as follows:

> It essentially amounts to fitting a support vector classifier in a
>   higher-dimensional space involving polynomials of degree d, rather
>   than in the original feature space.

However, it then proceeds to state that, when using a non-linear kernel, predictions are made using:

[image]

Now, the number of parameters in this equation is 1 + |S|, where |S| is the number of support vectors. If I were to use additional features explicitly instead, I would have an individual weight for each feature, which may amount to many more than 1 + |S| parameters. So, it seems that using the kernel gives less expressive power than using explicit features. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're right in the sense that you will fit more parameters if the number of features (|F|) is larger than |S|. Fitting an SVM with |S| < |F| will often be more accurate than a linear fit on F, since you're performing a non-linear fit to F. Think of the example in the left image

[image]

You can't make a linear combination of the given features (x and y axis) that separates the black and white labels perfectly, however you can make some non-linear transformation of F which does (right image). You could attempt to add transformations of your features as additional features (such as `[f_1, f_2, f_1*f_1, f_1*f_2, f_2*f_2]`, where `f_1, f_2` are your original features), or you can instead fit an SVM. In an SVM you don't make a linear fit of some transformed features, but you instead make a linear fit to how each data point relates to the support vectors via the chosen kernel.

A second consideration is that adding additional features that are unrelated to your labels introduce noise to your fit and might have non-zero weights since they pick up on some random pattern in your data. As such, fitting more parameters doesn't always help the model.

Comment: 1) I did not understand this. Why would the linear fit using explicit features be less accurate? 2) Such irrelevant features will probably receive zero weights, won't they?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I hopefully improved my answer.

Comment: 1) You explained very nicely how to correctly view what SVM does. However, this does not really address what exactly makes up for the expressiveness allowed by a large number of parameters when features are added. 2) If a feature is correlated with the data, then it's a relevant feature. If it is not, why would it receive a significant weight?

Comment: 1) I don't know how to extend my answer to answer what you feel is missing, so hopefully a different answer might help you. 2) By random chance simply. If you had infinite samples and finite features, then you're right, there shouldn't be a significant weight to non-relevant features. If you take 10 points on a straight line, add some random noise and fit polynomial features, you will often see a large weight on higher order terms.